# Putting bootstrap span inside haml link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

When my Bootstrap container is the width of a small device, I wish to decrease the size of my menu and have a "more" link, with a caret (downwards facing arrow) to indicate that there are more links to the menu.

The caret for Bootstrap comes as a span, but I am struggling to add it to a link in HAML.

First try:

```
%li.more.visible-sm
  = link_to "More", "#"
    %span.caret
```

Second try:

```
%li.more.visible-sm
  = link_to(content_tag(:span, "", :class => "caret") "More", "#"
```

Neither have worked. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a block like this:

```
%li.more.visible-sm
  = link_to "#" do
    More
    %span.caret
```